# Chromedriver - IE Tab permission not granted

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing web application. In my test I check client data. For use this test I need IE Tab in chromedriver. I'm initializing chromedriver with IETab correctly. After that page is display with below popup

[image]

With popup in console I see below log:

**Uncaught IETABAPI Error:  Permission not granted.  You must call window.ietab.requestAccess to use the IE Tab Api.**

I clik Allow and nothing's gonna happen. Correctly test should opening new bookmark in chromedriver. Below my code which is executing chromedriver with IETab.

```
default void ChromeExtensionIETab() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Dysk Google\\all\\testowanie\\chromedriver_win32\\extension_12_4_4_1.crx"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Dysk Google\\all\\testowanie\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
    getDriver().get("https://api-test/");
    getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(18, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Can someone explain me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise version of IE Tab includes permissions that would otherwise have to be manually enabled by your end users. [Read more here](https://www.ietab.net/grant-more-permissions).

*If IE Tab is installed:
[Click here to allow IE Tab to access https:// URLs and file downloads](https://www.ietab.net/grant-more-permissions#)*

*Enterprise customers please contact us at support@ietab.net to discover how to deploy these settings automatically.*

Comment: I click on this -> Click here to allow IE Tab to access https:// URLs and file downloads and nothing happends.

Answer (score 0):

What we don't see is the web page that you are "driving".

The pop-up you are seeing is from the IE Tab api which must first call window.ietab.requestAccess and wait for the result before calling window.ietab.openWithIETab.

The error you are seeing is because the page called window.ietab.openWithIETab without waiting for a response form requestAccess.

So the web-page is probably calling both calls without waiting for the result from requestAccess, perhaps because the developer had already allowed access so they aren't aware that this pop-up is showing any more.